# Refresh listing of the app document folder as soon as a file is created there

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am using a dropdown menu to display the names of files in my app's document folder. If I create a new file while the app is in session, I am not able to see the file name in the dropdown  as soon as I create it. How can I get this to work by refreshing it?

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you add or delete a file in application's document folder, applicationDidBecomeActive method of AppDelegate get notified.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Populate your dropdown here
    [self.viewController loadDropdown];    
}
```